# Modify Datatable Search Function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

If I type two strings divided by a space "abc xyz" into the search input, datatables finds the rows that contain both strings.

```
1 abc001 John London xyz
2 abc001 Mary NYC xyz
```

I want to find all rows that have abc and all rows that have xyz.

```
1 abc001 John London xyz
2 abc001 Mary NYC xyz
3 abc002 Susan LA qpr
4 xyz001 Peter Paris efg
5 xyz002 Michael Chicago efg
```

basically .. as I add strings I am expanding the search. Note there is no xyz in row 3, or abc in row 4 or 5.

I have a separate search function that does this. In fact it also does exclusions. So I can search a html table with multiple strings and also exclude some strings

```
function myFunctionS() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInputS");
  inputExclude = document.getElementById("myInputExcludeS");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  filterExclude = inputExclude.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("example");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      txtValue = txtValue.toUpperCase()
      let match = true
      let f = true // add this line
      filter.split(' ').forEach(q => {
        if(q && q.length > 0) {
          // and add these lines
          if(f) {
            match = false
            f = false
          }
          match = match || txtValue.indexOf(q) > -1  /// only change && instead ||
        }
     })
      filterExclude.split(' ').forEach(q => {
        if(q && q.length > 0)
          match = match && txtValue.indexOf(q) == -1
      })
      if (match) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
```

and the input fields are as:

```
<input type="text" id="myInputS" onkeyup="debounce(myFunctionS(), 500)" placeholder="Search for names..">
<input type="text" id="myInputExcludeS" onkeyup="debounce(myFunctionS(), 500)" placeholder="Exclude names.."/>
```

so I could search for "abc xyz" but exclude Chicago, and the result would be.

```
1 abc001 John London xyz
2 abc001 Mary NYC xyz
3 abc002 Susan LA qpr
4 xyz001 Peter Paris efg
```

This is a great function, but it doesn't work with Datatables. I have to load a html table of over a thousand rows into one page, with no pagination. Then this search function works great.
If I try to use it on a datatables paginated table, it only finds what's on the first page and the pagination is all thrown out of whack with the result.

Is there a way to integrate this search/exclude into datatables or at least modify datatables search so that it will find any row containing at least one of the multiple search strings.

Comment: Instead of searching through values in the HTML table elements, you can use the [DataTables search plug-in](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search) to search all data in the DataTable itself (regardless of visible/hidden data due to pagination, etc.). I expect the function in your question could be refactored to work with the input parameters provided by the DataTables search plug-in.